# Insert into sql, insert values within loop

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

What is the right syntax for code above?

```
$_POST[firstname{$i}],  $_POST[firstname+$i], $_POST[firstname.$i]
```

I searched over and over again but I couldn't find any answer yet : /

How am I suppose to put the $i  after those names?

Comment: you can use concat to put $i after those names.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax:

```
"... values ( ".$_POST['firstname'.$i]." ) ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $firstname =  $_POST['firstname'.$i];
```

and user `$firstname` variable in your query

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use array subscripts in a string like that. You'd have to write `"{$_POST['firstname'.$i]}"` (you were also missing the quotes around the first part of the array subscript, such as 'firstname').

If you plan on doing that though, you will open your application to hackers (read here on how to [prevent sql injections in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/112968)).

Answer (score 0):

- "hi dear mistysnake u can use **'Peter''".$i."'**  peter is the static value and u can insert value and your problem is the u can put the $_GET"